Probability of box remaining after selecting
Not sure if this is a potential duplicate, so apologies in advance.
Studying Rozanov's probability book, I created myself the following puzzle which I am struggling to solve: Assume there are 25 boxes. First, I remove 6 boxes, then I remove 5.

What is the probability that a box remains after the first round of picking?
What is the probability that a box remains after the second round if it remained after the first?

I have thought a bunch about this problem but I cannot arrive at a good solution for part 2.
Here is my thinking:

In the first round, the probability that a box is picked is

$$
P_C = \frac{1}{25\choose 6}
$$
Hence, probability that a box remains is $ P = 1 - P_C $

Here is my main trouble: After the first round, 19 boxes remain. After the second round, 14 will remain. To be in box collections, a box must have remained in the first round. The probability that a box is not picked in the second round is $$ P = 1 - \frac{1}{19 \choose 5} $$
And the probability that it is one of the previous 19 is, finally, $$ P = \frac{14}{19}\left(1 - \frac{1}{19 \choose 5}\right) $$

I feel like my answer is incorrect and I am not confident I understand how to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

I agree that using a math textbook to self-study is a good approach.  However, based on your posted article, I question whether you have find the right probability book for you.  I suggest that you print out this webpage, take it to a math professor, and have the professor recommend a probability textbook for you to self-study.

Surely the answers are simply 19/25 and 14/19?

You desire the probability that a particular box is 1 among the 6 boxes not removed when selecting from 25 boxes .

Your denominator, $\binom {25}{6}$, counts ways to select 6 boxes from 25. As you had.
However, you numerator should count ways to select your box and 5 others, in the same manner.  Which is  $\binom 11\binom{24}{5}$ .
So the probability you want is: $$P_C~=~\dfrac{\dbinom{24}{5}}{\dbinom{25}{6}}~=~\dfrac{24! / (5!~19!)}{25!/(6!~19!)}~=~\dfrac{6}{25}$$

Alternatively: Consider the process as randomly lining up the 25 boxes then removing the last 6 in line.  The probability that your box is one among those selected is simply: $$\dfrac{\dbinom {6}1}{\dbinom{25}1} = \dfrac{6}{25}$$

Hence the probability that the box remains after the first round is $19/25$.


The rest of your problem is solved in the same manner.
The conditional probability for remaining after the second round when remaining after the first is: $14/19$.
